# AngularJS $routeParams is undefiend, but property is there

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angularjs-ng-route

```
angular.module("newsApp",["ngRoute"])
.config($routeProvider=>{
    $routeProvider.when("/edit",{
        templateUrl : "views/addNewsView.html"
    });
    $routeProvider.when("/newsList",{
        templateUrl : "views/newsList.html"
    });
    $routeProvider.when("/singleNews/:newsId",{
        templateUrl : "views/singleNews.html"
    });
    $routeProvider.when("/",{
        templateUrl : "views/newsList.html"
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo:"/newsList"
    });
})
```

this is my module and config. i have simple app. i want to add functionality that when the user enters the url for  **example.com/singleNews/2** - it opens the news with ID - 2

```
.controller("newsAppCtrl",['$scope','$location','$routeParams',($scope, $location, $routeParams)=>{

    console.log($routeParams); //empty object

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log($routeParams); //in this case property is there
    },100);
```

So when i enter the url

> example.com/singleNews/2

the **routeParams** is empty object, although when i click to that empty object in chrome console the property is there and it says "value below was evaluated just now "
but when i add that console into TimeOut, it works and property is there. I know that using setTimeOut() is not recommended in angularjs, so using $timeout solved the problem, but i want to understand what is the problem.

Comment: 1) Add `controller : "newsAppCtrl"` to your config 2) Using `(...)=>{...}` syntax should cause an error (`... is not a constructor`), consider `function(...){...}` instead

Comment: thanks it worked. however can you explain why arrow function gives an error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be getting an error in your console:

> Function.prototype.bind.apply(...) is not a constructor

Simply avoid using `(...)=>{...}` syntax as AngularJS tried to call a function with `new method()` syntax and fails to do that with an arrow notation.

Switch `.config($routeProvider=>{...}` to `.config(function($routeProvider){...}` (and other similar cases).

*Arrow notation can still be used and is useful with* `$http` *calls, e.g:*

```
$http.get(url).then( (res)=>{...} );
```